# Compiling SCSS into CSS and transpiling ES6 to ES5 simultaneously

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

So I have a SCSS file called `style.scss`.  And I have an ES6 file called `script.js`.  Both these files are in a `./src/` directory.

I want to use Webpack to take the `style.scss`, convert it to CSS and stick it into a folder called `./dist/` with the filename `style.css`.  I can actually make that happen.

I also want Webpack to take the `script.js`, transpile to ES5, and put that in to the same `./dist/` folder with a file called `script.js`.  I can also make that happen.

What I cannot do, is make both happen simultaneously.  Is this something that Webpack can even do?  In this instance I don't want all my styles putting into my JS, I specifically want them to be kept in separate files like a standard website (as that's what this is, really).

The closest I have got is this:

```
 const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

 module.exports = {
     entry: {
       script: './src/script.js',
       style: './src/style.scss'
     },
     output: {
         path: './dist',
         filename: '[name].js'
     },
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.scss$/,
           use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
             fallback: "style-loader",
             use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
           })
         }
       ]
     },
     plugins: [
         new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
     ] }
```

But this gives me a `script.js` file, a `style.css` file and ALSO a `style.js` file which is a mess.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create a separate entry point for the CSS. You can either import the `style.scss` in your `script.js` or you can add it to the same entry. An entry can also be an array and webpack will include them in the same bundle, well the CSS is extracted anyway so there won't really be any additional JavaScript. Your entry would be as follows:

```
entry: {
  script: ['./src/script.js', './src/style.scss']
},
```